# Pass Parameters to a CustomAction and use the return value

Tags: wix

Is there a way to pass data to a (managed, C#) CustomAction?  Preferably using the CustomActionData collection of the Session object.  I would also like to use the return value from my CustomAction within my UI Control section.

More specifically, I want to allow the user to specify a Username and Password under which a service I am installing will run.  I have therefore created a dialog, when the user clicks Next I want to start a custom action that checks the credentials are valid.  The custom action will return Success if the account exists and some other value if it doesn't (preferably NotExecuted or SkipRemainingActions, but will settle for Failure).
Then in the (wxs) dialog if the custom action returns success just go to the next dialog (in the install sequence).  If the action returns the alternate value (NotExecuted) a SpawnDialog will appear telling the user that the account cannot be verified but they can continue if they like, using a yes or no button.

If someone can explain the best way to do this in Wix that would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the limitations of the windows installer UI, I decided to take a slightly different approach.  I now enable/disable the **Next** button depending on whether the basic field input is valid, i.e. if the **Username** field is empty then the button is disabled.  I use a (C#) CustomAction to validate that the user account exists, by passing the username/password via properties, and return the result in another property.  Back within the installer UI, if the account is invalid a message box appears.

I also provide a check box that allows the user to ignore the account check and just proceed.

I got the idea from https://geekproject.com/post/wix-service-account-dialog/

See the image below.

[image: Example dialog]

Answer (score 3):

Windows Installer doesn't really support this through C# custom actions.

WiX Toolset offered support for accessing installer properties from C#, but it does have some limitations. Additionally, I don't think you can control the custom action return code with it.

So the best solution remains a win32 DLL which receives the installation handle:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx

This way you can use the Windows Installer API to read and set properties:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370134(v=VS.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370391(v=vs.85).aspx

After creating the custom action, you can condition the next dialog with an installer property instead of a return code:

- condition the NewDialog control event which shows the next dialog
- condition a message box custom action which informs the user why he cannot continue or what his options are

Here is an article with more details: http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-user-interface/validate-user-input-installation/

This approach prevents the user from continuing with invalid data, but can easily be adapted to offer him some options and handle them automatically.

Comment: Actually Wix 3.5 does support access to the properties via a Session object, which is passed to the CustomAction.  That is how I have (now) implemented my requirement.  Rather than give the user a yes/no choice I simply display a warning message if they choose, via a checkbox, to not verify the account.